# Heroku Keeps tying to install Ruby 1.9.3 even after I upgrade my app to 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I just upgraded an old app from Heroky running ruby on rails. I upgraded both ruby 1.9.3 to 2.5.1 and rails 3.2 to 5.2.0.

Then I created a new app on Heroku and try to deploy, but I keep getting an error message saying Heroku cannot install 1.9.3.

Here is the error log:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-1.9.3-p551
remote:  !
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to nbmen-staging.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/nbmen-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'
```

In Gemfile.lock, I have:
    RUBY VERSION
       ruby 2.5.1p57

```
BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

There is also a .rbenv-version file and I changed the content from 1.9.3 to 2.5.1.

And I still gets the "An error occurred while installing ruby-1.9.3-p551" message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

seems like you may have an old/unrealeased heroku buildpack, as the bundler version is not being output in your build (and consequently you may be using an old bulder version).

What I would have expected to see is:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
...
```

To check your buildpack:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=> heroku/ruby
```

If it doesn't output `heroku/ruby`, then you are running an old/unreleased buildpack

To install the latest buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

For more information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version

Comment: I tried to install the buildpack, but I still got the same result when push to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby version file is now called `.ruby-version`.

The file that you have is called `.rbenv-version`. It's an old name and it's not supported anymore.

You can try renaming it.

Comment: I renamed the file, but still no luck.